# Creating Directories and Files from within Clearcase Remote Client for Eclipse

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-remote-client

I found [this page](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21245019), but it is odd because my context menu does not look anything like the one here. Indeed, it has no "New" submenu. I'm using CCRC 7.1 on RetHat 5.4 and Eclipse 3.7.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I found that the context menu for the "ClearCase Details" view in Eclipse has the missing "New" submenu.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't create files/directories directly from the CCRC sub-menu, one workaround would be to create them directly on your disk, within the web view itself.

Then an [update of the view](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrc.help.doc/topics/t_ccview_update.htm) would detect new resources to add to source control.

For CCRC 7.1, the [official documentation is here](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrc.help.doc/topics/t_mkelem.htm).

> Select the resources that you want to add to source control.
>   Use the ClearCase Navigator, **`ClearCase Details` view**, or `ClearCase Search Results` view.
>   If you are working in the Eclipse environment, use any Eclipse view that supports the Team context menu.